# versions:set plugin set the userdefined pom version but installing old version

Tags: maven

**Question :** versions:set plugin set the userdefined pom version but installing old version.

EX: I used command as versions:set -DnewVersion=43.0.2 clean install 
old version is 43.0.1, this set plugin suceessfully update pom version to 43.0.2 but while installing it refers old version as 43.0.1

Could you please help me on this..How can I install jar with updated new version

Comment: it is because the current version is 43.0.1 and even when you run the task mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=43.0.2 clean install. You need to split the execution. First update the version and then clean install.

Comment: But why so we need to do, with single line command as it is updating the new version but at the same time with install command it should install updated version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re *"with single line command as it is updating the new version but at the same time with install command it should install updated version":*

See [Versions Maven Plugin, Basic Usage](https://web.archive.org/web/20141006174057/http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/usage.html#Basic_Usage):

> *Maven 2.0, 2.1, 2.2 and 3.0 do not currently support re-reading*
>   *modifications of the `pom.xml` within one invocation of Maven.*

Comment: Thanks, really appriciate your comment.